# Understanding different Q-models of a curve over C

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

These are parametrized by $H^1(Gal(\mathbb{Q}), Aut X)$, where X is *some* $\mathbb{Q}$-model of the curve.

It was established in [Confusion about how the first cohomology classifies torsors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22907/confusion-about-how-the-first-cohomology-classifies-torsors)
that fiber bundles over $B$ with fiber $F$, structure group $G$ and transition maps with property $P$ are classified by $T$-torsors, where $T$ is the sheaf on $B$ of functions to $G$ with property $P$. $T$-torsors, in turn, are classified by $H^1(B, T)$.

Is there a way to interpret the aforementioned classification of $\mathbb{Q}$-models of a curve in these terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Roughly, the idea is that once your base object $X/B$ is fixed then for any object $Y$ you can consider the sheaf $Iso(X,Y)$ of isomorphisms from $X$ to $Y$.  This has an action of the sheaf $Aut(X)$ and on any open cover $U$ where $Y|_U \cong X|_U$, making a choice of such an isomorphism gives an isomorphism of $Aut(X)(U)$-sets $Iso(X,Y)(U) \cong Aut(X)(U)$.

The difference from the standard argument in this case is that you need to use the etale topology instead of the Zariski topology.  The etale covers of $\mathbb{Q}$ are finite field extensions $F$ and so the statement that $Y$ is "locally" equivalent to $X$ means that $Y_F \cong X_F$ for a large enough field extension $F$.

Comment: So, to be precise... We are looking in the etale topology; B is spec(Q); G is the sheaf into Grps: Aut(X); and P is... what?

Comment: I'd actually say that in the terminology you were originally using, G should be the group scheme of automorphisms of X and P should be simply algebraic maps.  Then T(Spec(F)) is the set of algebraic maps Spec(F) -> Aut(X), or the Spec(F)-points of Aut(X), or the automorphism group of `$X_F$` over Spec(F).

Comment: Huh.. I see. You say "group scheme of automorphisms". Is there any reason to believe it's representable?

Comment: You can show representability of Aut(X) (or more generally the existence of Isom-schemes) by identifying an automorphism with its graph $\Gamma \subset X \times X$, and construct a representing object inside a certain Hilbert scheme.  However, if you want to know more details about that you should ask another question so that a genuine algebraic geometer has the opportunity to answer.