# extension of $G$-bundles

Tags: principal-bundles, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth surface (let's say over an algebraically closed field) and let $D$ be a smooth divisor in $S$. Let also $G$ be a connected algebraic group. Assume that we are given a principal $G$-bundle ${\mathcal F}$ on $S\backslash D$. Under what conditions can we extend it to all of $S$? Do I understand correctly, that this is always the case when the derived
group $[G,G]$ is simply connected?

Comment: Sasha, there is a paper by Colliot-Thelene and Sansuc (I don't remember the title, but Keerthi M. does; hopefully he will see this) in the middle of which is buried of proof of the extension result for any connected reductive group when working over a regular 2-dimensional scheme with a torsor over complement of a codim-2 closed set (the proof views $G$ as subgroup of some GL$_n$ and affineness of GL$_n/G$ -- here is where reductivity is used -- to cleverly reduce the problem to GL$_n$). This reduces your question to the analogue for dvrs (i.e., just need to extend around generic pts of $D$).

Comment: @BCnrd: I would expect that such extension result holds for any affine $G$: to prove, reduce to $GL(n)$ by Tannakian formalism. More explicitly, if $f:T\to X$ is a $G$-torsor, then $f$ is affine, so the torsor is determined by the sheaf of algeras $f_*O_T$ equipped with an action of $G$. But the sheaf $f_*O_T$ is a union of locally free $G$-invariant subsheaves of finite rank (corresponding to f. dimensional subrepresentations of the regular representation). So if you want to extend a $G$-torsor, the problem reduces to extending a bunch of vector bundles (+compatibilities). 

Comment: The paper BCnrd refers to is: "Fibrés quadratiques et composantes connexes réelles", and the result is Thm 6.13. Link: http://www.springerlink.com/index/U5G225315W158721.pdf

Comment: Dear t3suji: Your suggested exhaustion by $G$-stable subsheaves doesn't seem to encode the torsor property. Here are some examples. Consider $G = {\rm{PGL}}_2$ -- so twisted forms of $\mathbf{P}^1$ -- and char. not 2. Viewing these canonically as smooth conics in a $\mathbf{P}^2$-bundle, if the generic fiber as a conic over the function field has discriminant whose divisor on $S$ has odd multiplicity somewhere then we cannot hope to extend around the corresponding codimension-1 point of $S$. There are these "ramification" obstructions at generic pts of $D$ in general. 

Comment: Dear Brian: This is encoded in the "+compatibilities" part. That is, you need a bunch of vector bundles and some extra data (action of G and product on their union). This causes problems when you extend across codimension one, as in your example: although vector bundles extend, you can't extend them compatibly. However, across codimension two, the extension of vector bundles is unique, and compatibility is automatic. Perhaps I should have been more explicit: `such extension result' meant the result you were quoting (by Colliot-Thelene and Sansuc), not the original question. --Dima

Comment: Yes, that is the argument I had in mind when you extend to codim 2. For me a $G$-bundle is by definition a tensor functor from the category of
representation of $G$ to the category of vector bundles. So, since extension of vector bundles to codim 2 (over 2-dimensional scheme) is canonical, it follows that it works also for $G$-bundles.

Comment: Dear Sasha: Is your definition of $G$-bundle equivalent to the "right" definition (i.e., G-torsor for etale or whatever topology) in the setting you describe?  (This is an idle question, since you really care about codim-1, whereas all good definitions coincide.)

Comment: Brian, it appeared on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2414/sheaf-description-of-g-bundles/2423#2423, and yes, it is equivalent.

Comment: Dear t3suji: Ah, I was getting myself confused due to the fact that the surface isn't Dedekind, but that doesn't matter since $G$ begins life over the field $k$.  So that equivalence is something I should have remembered.

Comment: However: see Minhyong Kim's answer below (which shows that the group must be reductive for extension to hold). Essentially, the point I was missing in the case of an arbitrary group is that the functor must be exact (which is automatic for reductive groups, but fails for arbitrary affine groups). So the Tannakian formalism implies the result of Colliot-Thelene and Sansuc (but it seems that their proof is in the similar spirit anyways), but the reductiveness (?) of G cannot be dropped.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the exactness of the functor. In fact, if I undersntad correctly, the fact that the functor is exact automatically for reductive groups is non-trivial in positive characteristic (but true, I think): it follows from Mumford's 
conjecture (proved by Haboush).

Answer (score 7):

Nick Shepherd-Barron once asked me this question, and I think I can remember what was eventually concluded.

The short answer to the original question is negative for the additive group $\mathbb{G_a}$. Map $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ to $X=\mathbb{C}^2-(0,0)$ by letting a matrix act on the vector $(1,0)^T$. This realizes the group as a torsor over $X$ for the group of unipotent matrices
\[
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\\\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}.
\]
We can trivialize it over the vectors $(v_1,v_2)^T$ with $v_1\neq 0$ with the section
\[
\begin{pmatrix} v_1 & 0 \\\\ v_2& v_1^{-1} \end{pmatrix},\]
while it trivializes on the set $v_2\neq 0$ via the section
\[\begin{pmatrix} v_1 & -v_2^{-1} \\\\ v_2& 0 \end{pmatrix}.\]
The transition function on the overlap is easliy computed to be
\[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & (v_1v_2)^{-1}\\\\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}.\]
This represents the standard non-trivial generator of $H^1(O_X)$, and hence, the bundle is non-trivial. On the other hand, if you could extend it to $\mathbb{C}^2$,  it would trivialize, since there are no non-trivial $\mathbb{G}_a$-bundles on an affine variety.

There is indeed a correspondence between principal bundles and tensor functors from representations to vector bundles. But if I recall correctly, the functor  is required to be exact. In the case at hand, the extension of vector bundles is the direct image with respect to the inclusion $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$, which fails this.

---

Added: OK, I see this was just an elaborate way to say: take any principal $\mathbb{G}_a$-bundle corresponding to a non-zero element of $H^1(O_X)$. Note, anyways, that the derived group is trivial in this example. Certainly the statement is false for general connected groups, contrary to some of the comments.

---

Added, 25, November, 2011:

This question came back to me today while I was thinking about something unrelated. It occurred to me then to point out that for the example above, if we work in the analytic category, we have
$$H^1(X, \mathbb{G}_a)\simeq H^1(X, \mathbb{G}_m),$$
via the exponential sequence. On the other hand, 
$$H^1(\mathbb{C}^2, \mathbb{G}_a)=H^1(\mathbb{C}^2, \mathbb{G}_m)=0.$$

So the desired extension property is false on analytic spaces even for reductive structure groups.

Comment: No worries, you are welcome!

Comment: Good point, thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 5):

Wait, are you assuming that G is a reductive group whose derived group is simply connected?  In that case, I believe Serre's Conjecture II implies that the G-torsor is trivial over a dense Zariski open subset of S.  So you can extend it across the codimension 1 points as a trivial torsor.

P.S.  Sorry for writing this as a separate answer, as opposed to a reply to Sasha's comment, but I don't know how to make replies in MathOverflow (maybe you need to be registered).

Comment: I wrote this before I saw Brian's comment.  I am just saying exactly the same thing as Brian, sorry!  Also I  just figured out how to make comments.

Comment: Jason--You appear to have multiple accounts; that prevents the accumulation of reputation points. You need at least 50 points in your account to comment on other people's answers. 

Comment: Ah, yes, you also need to register.

Comment: Jason, you don't need to register.  Just keep using the same account.

Comment: Jason, it is better to register. From the very beginning you can comment on _your own_ answers. After you accumulate 50 points, you will be able to comment on _other people's_ answers

Comment:  I would like to understand the connection to Serre's Conjecture II. Doesn't the notion of a G-torsor already include local triviality? Are we talking about a G-torsor for the Zariski or the etale topology? If we are talking about the Zariski topology why can't we first take a curve E in S-D so that the bundle trivializes on S-D-E and then glue with the trivial bundle on $S−\overline{E}$. Finally, we have to extend over $D \cap E$⎯⎯⎯ but this is codimension 2

Comment: I mean $D\cap \overline{E}$.

Answer (score 3):

For extension across codimension 2 points, in the case of a reductive group, you can use Hartog's theorem / S_2 extension.  As t3suji suggests, you embed G into GL_n and first extend the GL_n-bundle to a bundle E defined over all of S.  Via its embedding in GL_n, G acts on E.  Form the quotient space E/G.  Then the original G-bundle structure away from D gives a rational section of E/G.  Since G is reductive, E/G is affine over S.  So if you extend your section of E/G at codim 1 points, then Hartog's theorem extends across codim 2 points.  And the inverse image of this section of E/G in E is an extension of your original G-bundle.

Comment: Jason, if I understand correctly, you're outlining how to geometrically make the construction if it can be done at the codim-1 pts of D.  In general we may not be able to extend the section of $E/G$ around these points (as in the conic examples I mention above), unless I am misunderstanding something. The existence or not of this extended section seems to also depend on the choice of $E$, so it doesn't appear to show that the extension problem for the torsor at the generic pts of $D$ is etale-local on $S$. 

Comment: This is my understanding, too. (I guess my comment to the question was not quite clear on that, I tried to expand it.) 

Comment: My question really was when can you extend to codimension 1 -- for some reason I thought that having $[G,G]$ simply connected guarantees this. Am I wrong?

Comment: Let $R$ be a dvr (allowing imperfect residue field, if char($k) > 0$ above), $K$ the frac. field, and $G$ a *split* conn'd reductive $R$-group with simply conn'd derived gp. Is ${\rm{H}}^1(R,G) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(K,G)$ surjective, at least for $R$ excellent (e.g., local ring on surface)? Since $G/[G,G]$ is split torus, may assume $G$ is split semisimple and simply conn'd. Even if one has a version of Steinberg's vanishing result over a strict henselization, that seems too weak to help (since a finite sepble extn of $K$ unramified at one place over $R$ is usually ramified elsewhere). 

Comment: So, does it mean that you don't believe in this statement? Can you think of a counterexample? 

Comment: Dear Sasha: I didn't mean to suggest I believed it to be false; just that I was stuck on one way to make a proof.  But now I see it is fine for the case you care about, with $K$ the function field of a surface over an alg. closed field: the paper of deJong, He, and Starr proves that for such $K$, ${\rm{H}}^1(K,G) = 1$ for $G$ split and simply connected semisimple over the constant field (they also prove something stronger). So you can always make the codimension-1 extension by suitable gluing of a trivial torsor around the generic points of $D$. 

Comment: Great! That really helps! Does it also work when the base field is not algebraically closed, but finite?

Comment: Dear Sasha: If $k$ is finite, then is the connd reductive $G$ assumed to be $k$-split, and are the connd components of $D$ geom. connd?  (I assume $S$ is geom. connd.) If $K$ is the fn field of $S$, so $K_{\overline{k}} := K \otimes_k \overline{k}$ is the fn field of $S_{\overline{k}}$, then the geometric vanishing implies that the natural map ${\rm{H}}^1(k,G(K_{\overline{k}})) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(K,G)$ is surjective, so it raises the question of whether $G(R_{\overline{k}}) \rightarrow G(K_{\overline{k}})$ induces surjection on degree-1 $k$-cohom. Yuck; must be a better way (if true).

Comment: Yes, of course I am assuming that everything is split and connected.


Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea on how I would proceed if the field was $\mathbb{C}$. Let see $S=S\setminus\mathcal{N}(D)\cup \mathcal{N}(D)$ where $\mathcal{N}(D)$ is a normal neighborhood of $D$. You have a $G$ principal bundle $\mathcal{F}$ over $S\setminus\mathcal{N}(D)$ and you want to extend it to all $S$.

Basically you could do so if there is a $G$ principal bundle, $P$, over $S$ such that $\pi^*(P)=\mathcal{F}\vert_{\partial\mathcal{N}(D)}$ where $\pi$ is the natural projection from $\partial\mathcal{N}(D)$ to $D$.

I have the feeling that the only obstruction is that $\mathcal{F}$ has to be trivial when restricted to the fibers of the unit normal neighborhood of $D$ in $S$.

As we are talking about surfaces then $S$ is of real dimension $4$, if $D$ is of real dimension $2$ then those fiber have dimension $1$. And since you assumed that $G$ was connected then it is necessarily trivial on the fibers...

This is just some thought maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Note that if you're still in the case of $\mathbb{C}$ and that dimension of $D$ is $0$ then the triviality of $\mathcal{F}$ on the fiber depends on $\pi_2(G)$ so if $G$ is a Lie group $\pi_2(G)$ is trivial, thus you can extend as well...